# The argument of a vector field, also a function? Domain?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition, vector-analysis

Suppose I have a vector field $\mathbf A(x,y,z)$ such that
$$
\mathbf A(\mathbf r)=A_x(\mathbf r)\mathbf{\hat e}_x+A_y(\mathbf r)\mathbf{\hat e}_y+A_z(\mathbf r)\mathbf{\hat e}_z
$$
where $\mathbf{r}=x\mathbf{\hat e}_x+y\mathbf{\hat e}_y+z\mathbf{\hat e}_z=(x,y,z)$.

I know $\mathbf A(\mathbf r)$ is a function $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.

But what is $\mathbf r$ itself? Is it a function $\mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to already know $\bf r$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^3$.... You wrote ${\bf r}=(x,y,z)$, and you also write ${\bf A}({\bf r})$ is a function $\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$. both of which say $\bf r$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

No, $\mathbf{r}$ is just the independent variable in this context. You could have $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}(t))$, then $\mathbf{r}$ would be a function from $\mathbb{R}^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. (Similarly, it would be better to say that $\mathbf{A}$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ while $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r})$ is just a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but this type of abuse of notation is quite common.)